# How to read a JSON root array into a list?

Tags: python, json, string, list

I have a string containing a JSON array:

```
s = "['GY2_CAMP1', 'GY2_CAMP2', 'GY2_CAMP3', 'GY2_CAMP4', 'GY2_CAMP5']"
```

I tried to parse it as a JSON:

```
import json
l = json.loads(s)
```

I except to get a List, but an Exception has been raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/xx/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/xx/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home/xx/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

I am not sure what happens here.

Comment: Your string is not valid json. This works:

`s2 = s.replace("\'", "\""); l = json.loads(s2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval 
>>> s = "['GY2_CAMP1', 'GY2_CAMP2', 'GY2_CAMP3', 'GY2_CAMP4', 'GY2_CAMP5']"
>>> literal_eval(s)
['GY2_CAMP1', 'GY2_CAMP2', 'GY2_CAMP3', 'GY2_CAMP4', 'GY2_CAMP5']
```

Comment: Thank you. It is more elegant than replacing characters in the string before parsing as json.

Answer (score 1):

**Json standard requires double quotes**, it does not support single quotes.
That's why you get the error

Thus, the string should be

```
s = '["GY2_CAMP1", "GY2_CAMP2", "GY2_CAMP3", "GY2_CAMP4", "GY2_CAMP5"]'
```

Then you get the expected behaviour

```
import json
l = json.loads(s)
print(l)
>> ['GY2_CAMP1', 'GY2_CAMP2', 'GY2_CAMP3', 'GY2_CAMP4', 'GY2_CAMP5']
```

Answer (score 1):

First replace the `'` with `"` and then load.

```
import json
s = "['GY2_CAMP1', 'GY2_CAMP2', 'GY2_CAMP3', 'GY2_CAMP4', 'GY2_CAMP5']"
s.replace("'", "\"")

l = json.loads(s1)
print(l)
```

will get

```
['GY2_CAMP1', 'GY2_CAMP2', 'GY2_CAMP3', 'GY2_CAMP4', 'GY2_CAMP5']
```